# AVPlayerItem editing

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, avmutablecomposition, video-editing

I want to understand how a video editing app like iMovie on iOS handles changing the AVMutableComposition assigned to AVPlayerItem on the fly ? Example, user trims a video on the timeline, adds/modifies a text layer, adds a transition, etc. One way is to recreate a new AVMutableComposition object, create a new playerItem with this asset, and replace the currentItem of AVPlayer. I am not sure if this is the best approach and don't think iMovie app uses this approach, because there is a refresh on the player layer visible to user whenever you do this. Any ideas folks ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it creates another AVMutableComposition object or update the same AVMutabaleComposition, but there is a need to create new AVPlayerItem with updated AVMutableComposition every time and replace the currentItem of AVPlayer. What can be a better way.? I dont think there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Thats what I do, but still wondering what iMovie does as its UI is just seamless. For instance, you touch a title on the player layer and the text box borders it up. Edit the title and everything remains at the same place. The way that I do and you suggest, there is a minor UI refresh when the playerItem changes and you seek to the currentTime where you were before editing. 

Wondering it adds UITextField itself on the player layer or uses CATextLayer instead for title ? Any ideas ?